# How can I have a field show an asterisk with title attribute set to an error message with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently using ngMessages to control the display of messages on my form. Here's an example:

```
<div ng-messages="ahs.forms.modal.modalUserEmail.$error">
   <div ng-message="required">
      Email is required ...
   </div>
   <div ng-message="email">
      Email is not valid ...
   </div>
</div>

<div class="w50p">
   <span class="label">Email</span>
   <input id="modalUserEmail"
      ng-disabled="ahs.modal.disable"
      ng-model="ahs.modal.data.email"
      ng-required="true"
      name="modalUserEmail"
      type="email" />
</div>
```

What I would like to do is to change this and make it so that **to the right of Email title inside the span an asterisk appears** if either the Email is required or the Email is not valid. I would like the asterisk to have a title that shows the appropriate message when it is hovered over:

I know I can do something like this:

```
<span ng-show="home.forms.modal.modalUserEmail.$error.required">Required</span>
<span ng-show="home.forms.modal.modalUserEmail.$error.email">Invalid Email</span>
```

But how could I incorporate this into a title message?

```
<span class="label">Email</span>
<span ng-show="ahs.forms.modal.modalUserEmail.$error"
      title=
>*</span>
```

I am stuck on how to implement the 3rd line of this code and would appreciate any help / advice. I think possibly the answer may be

```
ng-attr-title or
ng-attr-title="{{ home.forms.modal.modalUserEmail.$error.required ? '*' : '' }}"
```

but I can't work out how I can use this and have it dynamically change the value of the ng-attr-title based on the value of the modalUserEmail.$error and one or more possible other errors **but just one error message at a time**. So that it would show "Required" or "Invalid Email" but not both error messages as the title at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly I would use an OR expression in the directive. Like this:

```
<span ng-attr-title="{{home.forms.modal.modalUserEmail.$error.required ||
    home.forms.modal.modalUserEmail.$error.someOtherError ||
    home.forms.modal.modalUserEmail.$error.aThirdError}}"
>*</span>
```

The above code will try to set the title to $error.required or $error.someOtherError or $error.aThirdError. If multiple of them are set it will use whichever comes first in the expression. If none of then are defined it will not set anything at all.